# How can data records appended to a target Oracle table that have subsequently been removed from its data source be identified in the target?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Periodically, an Oracle table called ED is updated through a stored procedure. The data source is a complex INSERT-SELECT statement and ED is truncated each time an update occurs. However, before truncation occurs, it is desired to know if any records existing in ED will not reoccur on the update i.e. the INSERT-SELECT will not reintroduce certain records that currently exist in ED.

The idea to solve this problem is to first perform the INSERT_SELECT into a temporary table called ED_TEMP. And then compare ED with ED_TEMP and place removed records in another table called ED_MISSING.

```
INSERT INTO ED_MISSING (ED_ID, ENTRY_DATE)
    SELECT DISTINCT ED_ID, ENTRY_DATE FROM ED
    WHERE ED_ID NOT IN (SELECT ED_ID FROM ED_TEMP);
```

Afterwards, it is desired to truncate ED and repopulate it with ED_TEMP.  Can this all be done within a stored procedure? Or would multiple stored procedures be better?

```
1. Truncate ED_TEMP.
2. Perform complex INSERT-SELECT to populate ED_TEMP.
3. Handle exception if necessary
4. Perform compare and populate ED_MISSING
5. Handle exception if necessary.
6. Truncate ED.
7. Populate ED with ED_TEMP.

Would separate COMMIT and EXCEPTION statements be necessary for each INSERT step?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Littlefoot's answer, I solved the problem in the following manner.

Create a stored procedure (ED_MAIN) that calls two other stored procedures. The first stored procedure (POPULATE_ED_TMP) truncates and then repopulates a temporary table ED_TMP.  The second stored procedure then does an insert into a ED_MISSING table.

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ED_MISSING(column1,...) --a primary key or unique index
SELECT column1,... FROM
(
SELECT column1,... FROM ED  -- the previous data set in the ED table
MINUS
SELECT column1,... FROM ED_TMP --the current data set
)
MINUS
SELECT column1,... FROM ED_MISSING --don't put duplicates in ED_MISSING
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Insert into GATED_MISSING error - '||    SQLCODE||' - '||SQLERRM); 
END;
```

Finally, in ED_MAIN move contents of ED_TMP to ED in prep for next comparison

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ED'
INSERT INTO ED(column1, column2, column3, column4,...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4,... FROM ED_TMP
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can this all be done within a stored procedure?

Sure; you'd just have to truncate tables using `execute immediate` as `truncate` is DDL. Also, note that DDL implicitly commits, twice - before and after actual DDL statement.

---

> Or would multiple stored procedures be better?

Can't tell; if the whole process makes one transaction, keep it in the same procedure. Or, if it is really complex, it is easier to maintain it if it is split into smaller pieces. Some people say that *ideal* procedure size is one screen height (so that you can see everything at once). I don't think that it is *always* possible, though.

---

> Would separate COMMIT and EXCEPTION statements be necessary for each INSERT step?

It depends; commit ends a transaction so - if something goes wrong afterwards, there's no rollback. Therefore, if everything you do is considered to be the same transaction, commit once - at the end. However, if you manipulate with huge data, rollback segment might not be able to *swallow* it all so you might need to commit during the process.

As of exceptions, you know the best. If there are e.g. 2 `select` statements, you can have one exception handler for `no_data_found`. But, it'll handle BOTH selects; how will you know which one failed? In that case, encapsulate each of them into its own `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block.

Comment: Don't have deep experience with this stuff. Can I have multiple BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END blocks in a single stored procedure? And if I perform an INSERT into ED_TEMP, I don't have to commit it to be able to compare it to the ED table right?

Comment: You can have as many BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END blocks within the single procedure (i.e. the "outermost" BEGIN-END) as you want, no problem. Yes, you're right - you don't have to COMMIT to use data in the ED table. Any changes you make within your own session is always visible to you (but nobody else, until you COMMIT).